# SyncFusion Gantt chart PDF export issue: Any workarounds for displaying chart and table together with proper formatting?

Tags: angular, charts, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion gannt chart in angular
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/gantt/getting-started
It provides default export for PDF but facing 2 issues

1. grid and chart does not render together, instead first it will display grid and after finish of grid it shows chart, which is difficult to understand for user which activity is for which chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1peDA.png)

2.Client are looking for header for PDF export.

Syncfusion does not support these features currently, please suggest some work around for this.

1. Tried to make some configuration changes in syncfusion with zoom in feature and tries to display table and graph together but facing issue while there is dependency in chart, dependency looks massy and wrong after pdf with zoom fit.
2. Tried to customize dom element of gantt chart to add Header but after doing this CSS are not getting applied on chart export which makes pdf ugly.